# Specifying Maven Directory when Running Java.exe

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spark-java

I'm a newbie to Java (just two days) and am trying to get an HTTP server running using Spark. I created a new Maven project in IntelliJ and have a Hello World response coming back from Spark when running it in IntelliJ. As a learning exercise, I would like to get the app running from the command line using Java.exe. When I run `java Main`, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError:
>   java.lang.NoClassDef oundError: spark/Request
>           at Main.main(Main.java:5) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Request
>           ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.Request
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 1 more

Looks like it can't find the Spark .jar files. There's a command line option `-cp` to specify paths to dependencies. After looking up where Maven keeps these files, I tried running:

> java -cp .;C:\Users\jbuschmann.m2\repository Main

Still same error. How do I specify the path to the Maven dependencies?

Comment: You could run `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"`. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846046/run-main-class-of-maven-project

Comment: see also https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the repository in the -classpath, try adding the location of your spark.jar.

```
java -cp \path\to\spark.jar Main
```