# MapDB ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, noclassdeffounderror, mapdb

I am trying to run a simple mapdb example, but get the error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at org.mapdb.DBMaker.fileDB(DBMaker.kt)
    at leechies.Truc.main(Truc.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

My class:

```
package leechies;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

import org.mapdb.DB;
import org.mapdb.DBMaker;

public class Truc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DB db = DBMaker.fileDB("file.db").make();
        ConcurrentMap map = db.hashMap("map").createOrOpen();
        map.put("something", "here");
        db.close();
    }
}
```

My pomx.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapdb</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I run with rigth click -> Run as... -> java application.

Comment: try clean and build project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846046/run-main-class-of-maven-project#9846103

Comment: I had the same issue from the command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either `kotlin-runtime` has to be in `classpath` and verify with `$ echo $CLASSPATH`.

Or you have to add `kotlin-runtime` to maven and then assemble inside the jar itself with `mvn compile assembly:single`,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

which need to be attached to artifact as well and can be done with `assembly-plugin`.

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>event.handlers.InventoryEventHandler</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

you can verify the kotlin-runtime is added to jar by

```
$ jar -tf target/amz-wavelength-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep kotlin-runtime
META-INF/kotlin-runtime.kotlin_module
```

or

```
$ jar -tf target/amz-wavelength-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep "kotlin/jvm/internal/*"
```

Answer (score 3):

@prayagupd's answer works for me.  But I thought it worth mentioning that another option is to use the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) instead of the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) (put this in the `build/plugins` section of your pom.xml file):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The shade plugin is nice because it allows you to exclude duplicate classes.  If you have to use either plugin, it's good to know you don't need both.  Build time and resulting jar file sizes are nearly identical in my quick tests, but the assembly plugin (that prayagupd suggested) doesn't add a bunch of warnings to my build output, so I'm going with that.

Answer (score 2):

It will fail because you do not have the necessary kotlin runtime jar in your classpath. You have to run some command to resolve this error. please refer this link for commands:-

https://dzone.com/articles/exercises-in-kotlin-part-1-getting-started

Comment: Its better, but then I get: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/MutableLongList

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run your class from maven, it will add all necessary dependencies.

[run main class of Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846046/run-main-class-of-maven-project#9846103)