# How do I create a jar with all dependencies using Gradle 4.4?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4894308/6296561) -- however, due to the deprecation of `compile` in favor of `implementation`, it doesn't work. It does pick up dependencies that are declared with `compile`. However, with it being deprecated, using it isn't an option (and we'd be right back here when it's removed anyway)

---

I got this Gradle task:

```groovy
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'rpi-sense-hat-lib',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.Tests'
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from { 
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```

And there's just one dependency, looking aside test dependencies:

```groovy
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Running from the IDE works fine. However, when I deploy to my Raspberry Pi (or use the jar `gradlew fatJar` results in locally), I get this exception:

```
$ java -jar java-sense-hat-1.0a.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.UtilsKt.getSenseHat(Utils.kt:18)
    at io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.SenseHat.<init>(SenseHat.java:12)
    at io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.Tests.main(Tests.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Which is triggered by this line:

```java
return Optional.empty()
```

in a Kotlin method returning an `Optional<File>`. [Answer on related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44734211/6296561):

> Either kotlin-runtime has to be in classpath and verify with $ echo $CLASSPATH.
>
> Or you have to add kotlin-runtime to maven and then assemble inside the jar itself with mvn compile assembly:single,

Which means the kotlin-runtime isn't included in the classpath. Before you go ahead and answer "add kotlin-runtime to your dependencies", it's a part of the [stdlib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime):

> Kotlin Runtime (deprecated, use kotlin-stdlib artifact instead)

I use `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` and it works in the IDE. Just for testing purposes, using `kotlin-stdlib` instead does not change anything.

In addition, replacing `implementation` with `compile` fixes it.

In the post I linked at the top of the question, there's a suggestion to use `runtime` in the fatJar task. So:

```groovy
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'rpi-sense-hat-lib',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.Tests'
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```

The dependency is still not included, and the program crashes.

So why not add implementation as a configuration to copy from?

I tried. I ended up with this:

```groovy
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'rpi-sense-hat-lib',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.Tests'
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
        configurations.implementation.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```

And an exception:

> Resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed

So, considering:

- `compile` instead of `implementation` works
- The runtime exception is from Kotlin not being in the classpath
- It works in the IDE
- Adding an `implementation` clause to the `fatJar` task crashes the compiling with a separate exception

How do I generate a jar with all dependencies in Gradle 4.4 when using the `implementation` keyword?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Gradle to build a jar with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies)

Comment: @ShafinMahmud read the question. It doesn't work with the implementation keyword

Comment: It would be nice if you reword your question title that describes the problem more specifically

Comment: @ShafinMahmud Did you flag as a duplicate because of the title? The content of the post covers the entire problem, including why the linked one doesn't work

Comment: But your question title should be distingusible with existing ones. No offense, there should be  a clear title that summaries your problem, not something generic if there is already something about that. That will lead people help you more

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried the [Shadow Plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) like:

```
shadowJar {
  manifest {
     attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'rpi-sense-hat-lib',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.Tests'
  }
  configurations = [project.configurations.compile, project.configurations.runtime]
}
```

Edit:

You can also do this (as described in an answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910578/not-able-to-copy-configurations-dependencies-after-upgrading-gradle-plugin-for-a)):

```
configurations {
    fatJar
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    fatJar "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'rpi-sense-hat-lib',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.Tests'
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from {
        configurations.fatJar.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```

but then you have to repeat all implementation dependencies as fatJar dependencies. For your current project it's fine since you have only one dependency, but for anything bigger it will become a mess...

Edit 2:

As @Zoe pointed out in the comments this is also an acceptable solution:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'rpi-sense-hat-lib',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'io.github.lunarwatcher.pi.sensehat.Tests'
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```

however make notice as per [source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/0abdea078047b12df42e7750ccba34d69b516a22/subprojects/plugins/src/test/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaLibraryPluginTest.groovy#L91) that `runtimeClasspath` is a combination of `runtimeOnly`, `runtime` and `implementation`, which may or may not be desirable depending on the situation - for instance you may not want to include `runtime` dependencies because they are provided by the container.

Comment: It works when I remove `configurations` and add `with jar`. Otherwise it still crashes with the missing library. Isn't there a way to do it without the plugin?

Comment: Found something (posting it as a comment since you already have an answer). I found [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/1ce4a51e0bb9cb474bec16bf41032d5351551355/subprojects/plugins/src/test/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaLibraryPluginTest.groovy#L101). Your edit reminded me that the configurations are defined somewhere, and I also saw a graph for the java-library plugin (I don't use it though) that reminded me there might be inheritance.

Comment: The link contains the definition of implementation and some of the other configurations, but the line itself is to runtimeClasspath. Using `runtimeClasspath` in the fatJar fixed it. Using a plugin is of course an option too, but I'd prefer not to