# Maven Project: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/KTypeBase

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I keep running into the error in the title whenever I use most of the functions for KClass that involve two different classes (`isSubclass()`, `isSuperclass()`, and even `.superclasses.forEach {}`) whenever I run it in InteliJ

I've already tried the solution detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425367/mapdb-classnotfoundexception-kotlin-jvm-internal-intrinsics), and even tried updating the kotlin-runtime dependency they said to include to version 1.2.0 (1.3.0+ don't exist)

```kotlin
class EditorObject(base: KClass<*>,test: KClass<*>) {

    init {
        if(!base.isSuperclassOf(test)){
            println("${AnsiColor.YELLOW}WARNING: Non-BaseObjects are not supported.${AnsiColor.RESET}")
            println("test")
        }
        println("got here")
        val init = base.primaryConstructor

    }
}
```

Only crashes if base!=test.